# Trying to Delete Rows of a Table

Tags: javascript, html

So i have a chat room im working on in html and im having an issue, that chatroom is local wifi, and what im trying to do is if i enter a code in an input box, clear the table or current chat.

```
            <script>
              function myFunction() {
                var letter = document.getElementById("pass").value;
                var text;

                if (letter === "Python") 
                  {
                  document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(0);
                  } else {
                  alert("Admin Access Denied");
                  }
                }
            </script>
```

this is what happens, so say i enter Python in the input box, the code works and it deletes the first line of the table every time i hit enter, and gives an alert if its wrong, but the issue is once i hit enter and it erases the first line, but then i cant put anything in the chat anymore, but when i reload the page it brings back everything i deleted. Also when i delete some lines, it only deletes for me and not everyone else in the room.

I need it to be able to not only erase the entire contents of the table, but i also need it to delete it permanently for everyone in the chat room and the chat room still able to work properly.

LINK: https://project-js-imthatguy.c9users.io/

Answer (score 2):

Just because you are deleting the first row in YOUR browser doesn't mean that the HTML will render differently the next time or for everyone else. This deletion needs to happen server side. Consider an AJAX call instead.

Comment: You will need to create an endpoint to which you can accept and process your ajax request. I suggest using jQuery's ajax api. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: there are things going on server side, like when someone gets on the website, it automatically adds an "anonymous" to the Users tab until they change their name, once they input their name the "anonymous" changes to what ever they type and its pretty quick, and every time a message is sent its pretty quick

Comment: again, i have never used AJAX and am clueless on how or what to do

Comment: @ImThatGuy: Luckily you have the internet available to you filled with tons of information and examples of using AJAX. The link I provided is the documentation for it. You should check it out.

Comment: ima be honest, im still very lost on how to do this

Comment: @ImThatGuy: If you are just deleting DOM elements through JS in your browser, how would this show for everyone else? The server knows nothing about what you deleted. That's why you should use ajax. It lets you send a request to the server with some data. With this you can tell the server what you've deleted.

Comment: ok i see what your saying, but im unsure how to use AJAX with html, i have read the document you sent me but im still having issues because i have never used AJAX before